# Image inside of an Checkbox in Android

Tags: android

"I am attempting to insert an image within a checkbox element, but I am encountering difficulty in displaying the image within the application. Although I am able to successfully select the checkbox, the image is not being rendered on the page."

Here is my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".HouseList">

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/my_checkbox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="My Checkbox"
        android:button="@drawable/custom_checkbox"
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/custom_checkbox" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And Here is my 'custom_checkbox.xml':

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/checkbox">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:id="@+id/check_image">
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/town1"
            android:gravity="center" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

I tried to follow few instructions that I found on Stackoverflow and some other websites, but none of them were helpful to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Update your file to use a layer-list for the checkbox and for the check box implement a separate drawable

Check the following sample selector:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="false">
        <layer-list>
            <item android:id="@android:id/background">
                <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>
                </shape>
            </item>
            <item android:id="@android:id/checkbox">
                <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>
                </shape>
            </item>
        </layer-list>
    </item>
    <item android:state_checked="true">
        <layer-list>
            <item android:id="@android:id/background">
                <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>
                </shape>
            </item>
            <item android:id="@android:id/checkbox">
                <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>
                </shape>
            </item>
            <item android:id="@android:id/check"
                  android:drawable="@drawable/town1"/>
        </layer-list>
    </item>
</selector>
```

This selector while covers different states of checkbox, you can either keep or remove any state if not in your scope.

Now in your main xml where you are using checkbox, give a reference of above selector drawable like this:

```
<CheckBox
android:id="@+id/my_checkbox"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="My Checkbox"
android:button="@drawable/custom_checkbox" />
```

I hope it works for you

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for drawable for custom_check

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
       android:state_checked="false"/>
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
       android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"/>
</selector>
```

Now Give the reference of above selector drawable to your main xml

```
<CheckBox
android:id="@+id/my_checkbox"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="My Checkbox"
android:drawableEnd="@drawable/custom_checkbox"
android:drawablePadding="10dp" />
```